# What are the cheapest ways from Russia to Brazil?

Tags: air-travel, budget, russia, routes, brazil

I'm looking for tickets for `OVB`=>`CWB`=>`OVB`, but the prices are so ridiculous that I need to shorten this to `MOW`=>`SAO`=>`MOW` (flying some legs separately makes it cheaper).

But even with `MOW`-`SAO` the problem is that all trips are quite costly and have very restrictive rules: round trip is a lot cheaper than one way, but if you lose one leg, you're screwed and lose everything. There are flights through `JFK`, but I prefer to stay away from their ridiculous security measures.

Turkish Airlines offer `OVB`-`GRU` with just 1 stop in `IST`, but now its prices also grew.

Are there any shortcuts for transatlantic routes to Brazil, like mass sales, or special destinations?

---

[This is what I found on Kayak](http://www.kayak.ru/flights#/MOW-SAO/2013-03-15-flexible/2013-05-30-flexible), (excluding Delta) although it was cheaper for these dates few weeks ago.

Comment: Welcome to the site.  What dates are you looking to fly?  Also the issue flying from Novosibirsk is that most price engines allow maximum of 2 stops.

Comment: @Karlson: well, it's negotiable. SAO-CWB flights are frequent, and there's a shuttle between Congonhas and Guarulhos. The Russian side is more problematic.

Answer (score 3):

I recently came accross a novel webservice where you can search from country to country level. [Russia - Brazil](http://www.rome2rio.com/s/Russia/Brazil?dates=2013-3-22/2013-4-17) will start at 1200 EUROs, when traveling next month.

Also not using one leg of a return ticket is only a problem if you miss the initial journey. Once you miss one flight, airlines typically will not allow you to travel further or on your return trip.

Comment: Yes, that's what I meant, you lose everything since the missed leg.

Comment: Hm, well, I managed to find Swiss flights DMD-ZRH-GRU at 750 eur.

Comment: Don't miss a leg then? Instead, plan your trip so you've a few days in the last city at the end, so you know you won't be late!

Comment: @hippietrail I think euros

Answer (score 3):

First of all, welcome to the Travel.SE, my russian friend.

In Saint-Petersburg we have a cheat which can help you to get cheaper tickets - **fly from Finland**. If you are considering flights from Moscow, you can travel from there to Helsinki with transit via Saint-Petersburg. You can do that with cheap train, if you buy tickets in right time, and after that using numerous cheap buses from Saint-Petersburg.

[Example of prices from Helsinki](http://www.kayak.ru/flights#/HEL-SAO/2013-03-15-flexible/2013-05-30-flexible) (you can use other airports, and get more variants).

The only thing you have to do is to get Shengen visa from Finland, and this can be a problem. But if you have such opportunity, consider this option - it is much more cheaper than fly directly from Russia.

Good luck with your travels.

Comment: The problem is flying Novosibirsk to SPb costs twice as much as Novosibirsk-Moscow, and you have to get their visa in Moscow, and pay for a bus. I lived there and rode there, and it's worth only for SPb residents. Thanks for an idea anyway.

Comment: @culebrón I thought you have a cheap variant to get to the Moscow

Comment: I do have it, but can't understand what you mean. Moscow is a bit more expensive than flying from Helsinki, but getting to Helsinki is more expensive.